# How to use google analytics api for specific user pages

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

A registered user on my site has their own page. I would like to provide them with some basic analytics for page views: View count, referrer, browser, OS and country. The user should be able to filter by hour, day, week, month and all.
Can I use Google Analytics API to implement this on my site?

I'm trying to understand the process.

- Create analytics account.
- Add tracking code to my site.
- For each user query API based on parameter page url (eg, mysite.com/userpage1) + date range.

  https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=...&start-date=...&end-date=...&metrics=...&dimensions=...

Questions:

- Should I use API v3 or v4?
- What are valid date ranges, can it be any DateTime value? Eg. 22/01/19 8:00:00 AM to 22/01/19 9:00:00 AM
- Can I use one query to get view count, referrer, browser, OS and country for a page based on a certain date rage? Not sure what metrics and dimensions I need to use. If you can please provide me with a sample query.
- If the analytics account is GMT +00:00, how would I deal with this for different user locals? Get the users region convert to DateTime.UtcNow, do the query and the convert back to local DateTime?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  In the future you should do your own research to start with by checking the documentation and then come here when you have **ONE** question you can ask asking a large number of questions doesnt really work here.   It also shows that you haven't checked the documentation at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I use API v3 or v4?

When starting a new project its always best to use the latest version of an api as the older version will at some point be shutdown.

> What are valid date ranges, can it be any DateTime value? Eg. 22/01/19 8:00:00 AM to 22/01/19 9:00:00 AM

Google analytics started 2005 so as long as the start date is there and the end date should around 48 hours ago due to data latency.   Also you do not send a time its just the date. You should consult the documentation.

> Can I use one query to get view count, referrer, browser, OS and country for a page based on a certain date rage? Not sure what metrics and dimensions I need to use. If you can please provide me with a sample query.

You should consult the documentation I cant make a query for you as only you know what data you need and you will probably not be using the same programming language i am

> If the analytics account is GMT +00:00, how would I deal with this for different user locals? Get the users region convert to DateTime.UtcNow, do the query and the convert back to local DateTime?

I think that even considering that would give me a headache i wish you luck with that idea. The data in Google analytics is a multi dimensional analysis.  I have no idea how you would intend to figure out the current users time zone and then change it to the actual time zone of the account and then only request results for them out of that time zone.  Again i wish you luck

**From Comments**

> So it not possible to get say the view for the last hour?

You can use the Real-time api if you want data now but your issue will be with the Quota.  You can only make 10k requests per day against a single view.  The real-time api can quickly eat that.

> I specified what data I want view count and referrer, browser, OS, country for each view based on a date range. Is it not possible to create a single query for this or you're not sure how it would be done?

Yes its possible. I suggest you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) for the names..

```
     "reportRequests":[
      {
        "viewId":"XXXX",
        "dateRanges":[
          {
            "startDate":"2015-06-15",
            "endDate":"2015-06-30"
          }],
        "metrics":[
          {
            "expression":"ga:sessions"
          }],
        "dimensions": [
          {
            "name":"ga:browser"
          }, {
            "name":"ga:os"
          },
{
            "name":"ga:country"
          }]
        }]
    }
```

> Not sure what you mean by your last answer, can you please elaborate. How would you solve it?

No i cant elaborate any more than i have as I would not solve it.  What you are doing is not going to work you can only make 10k requests per view against this api every day I cant see how you intend to get the data for every user on your site unless you possibly only have 100 users.

Comment: So it not possible to get say the view for the last hour?

Comment: I specified what data I want view count and  referrer, browser, OS, country for each view based on a date range. Is it not possible to create a single query for this or you're not sure how it would be done?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your last answer, can you please elaborate. How would you solve it?

Comment: Ok thank you. I guess that answers my first question: Can I use Google Analytics API to implement this on my site? Based on my prerequisites it's not possible...

Comment: If the answer helped you remember to accept it you will improve your reputation by asking well revived questions and getting answers.